# Loading the WCF configuration from different files on the client side

Tags: c#, wcf, load, configuration-files, wcf-client

A common problem in WCF that many people face is the impossibility of loading the client configuration from different configuration files.

This is a common scenario  when the developer wants to deploy some binaries with along with an independent configuration file (Which may be in a resource file also or another configuration file) to avoid modifying the main configuration file.

I have found two references:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/

which is the best solution about it ??

any suggestions for a the best solution ? I use VS 2008 and .NET 3.5.

Comment: You need to open up a separate question. Also, aborting at thread isn't the same thing as aborting the channel, which is what I think you're asking when you say "close vs. abort".

Answer (score 2):

The first link (blog post) is more relevant to your situation. Your only other option would be to use [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) to discover your endpoint and configuration at runtime, but that approach is certainly more work and can get complicated in managed mode.

Comment: True, out of the box WCF Discovery uses 4.0. You can always roll your own discovery though, and if you're interested in a WCF product that comes out of the box with Discovery that works in 3.5, take a look at http://soacollective.com/ecollective.

Comment: Any full source code sample using ***WCF Discovery 4.0*** for _NET 4.6.1_ ?