# close vs abort ChannelFactory WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, abort, channelfactory

Two common problems in WCF that many people face is the impossibility of loading the client configuration from different configuration files and Close vs Abort issue.

1.)

This is a common scenario when the developer wants to deploy some binaries with along with an independent configuration file (Which may be in a resource file also or another configuration file) to avoid modifying the main configuration file.

I ask question here:

[Loading the WCF configuration from different files on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633541/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side)

References:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/

2.) I'm confused too about Close vs Abort

References:

Wcf Service Proxy Helper http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx

Why does ClientBase Dispose need to throw on faulted state? (Or, what's the difference between close and abort?) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b95b91c7-d498-446c-b38f-ef132989c154/

Ideal target for me: Load configuration from different files on the client side and helper class for manage Close-Abort.

I need use CustomChannelFactory and manage exceptions for Close-Abort channel.

I have seen many-many references, and it's very much confused for me.

any suggestions for a the best solution ?

I use VS 2008 and .NET 3.5.

More references:

RotemBloom -Disposing of WCF Proxy

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/rotemb/archive/2008/07/30/WCF-Best-Practices_3A00_-How-to-Dispose-WCF-clients.aspx

WenlongDong -Open WCF Proxy Explicitly

http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx

WenlongDong -WCF Proxy Creation in .NET 3.5

http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx

Michele LerouxBustamante -WCF Proxy Wrapper

http://www.dasblonde.net/2008/04/24/MyProxyWrapperAndTheEVILSUOFile.aspx

Erwynvan derMeer -WCF Proxy Helper

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx

RotemBloom -WCF Proxy Function

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/rotemb/archive/2008/07/01/wcf-practices-writing-single-function-for-your-entire-wcf-proxy-calls.aspx

"vipulm" -Dynamic WCF Proxy from Metadata
http://wcf.netfx3.com/files/folders/development_tools/entry6148.aspx