# Openning Async WCF Service with wrong Username-Password hangs

Tags: wcf, authentication, asynchronous

I have a WCF service that implements the 'Custom-Username-Password-Validator'.

The service itself checks the username+password against a local file,

and if there is no match - it throws a *FaultException* with a message.

.

When I use the service synchronously it works fine.

When I go to work with it **ASYNC**, I have a problem.

If I pass the **wrong** 'Username+Password' credentials - and open the client,

instead of returning immediatly from the service going into my 'Channel_Faulted()' method,

the client thread simply waits until the *Timeout* triggers,

and then I get a 'TimeoutException'.

```
try
{
    client = new MyServiceClient("WSDualHttpBinding_IMyervice");
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "bad password";
    client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += new EventHandler(ChannelFactory_Faulted);
    client.Open();   // This hangs for 01:00:00 minute

    // Doesn't reach here
    client.DoSomethingCompleted += new EventHandler<DoSomethingEventArgs(client_DoSomethingCompleted);
    client.DoSomethingAsync(param);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Enters here with a 'TimeoutException' exception
}
```

why does the client not trigger the 'Faulted' method I have ?

Why does it wait for a response from the service even though the service through a 'FaultException' during the 'Validate' method of the 'CustomUserNameValidator' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the code you are using appears to be missing 3 lines after your code line:
    `client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += new EventHandler(ChannelFactory_Faulted);`

But again, I'm taking a shot in the dark since I've not made use of this option yet.

`var local = client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();`

`((IClientChannel)local).Faulted += ChannelFaulted;`

`local.Open();`

Better yet, the open method doesn't appear to be necessary according to the sample provide here: [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not used the ChannelFactory.Faulted event handler however, here is a post for your consideration: [creating-wcf-channelfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200197/creating-wcf-channelfactoryt)

Comment: I don't have any problem with hooking up the 'Faulted' event. The problem is - that instead of being fired - it isn't fired and a timeout occurs. Please notice that this happens only if I throw a 'FaultException' during the 'username+password custom validator'. If I throw a 'FaultException' during one of the service's operations - everything works fine, and the 'Faulted' event is raised...