# WCF ChannelFactory (caching, exceptions)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, caching, channelfactory

I have a web application that serves users through connections to other third party web services.

I am not sure about the safe/efficient way to create those web service clients in my application.

As of .NET 4.5, I can use client code generated through svcutil and cache channel factories per service by setting the static CacheSetting property.

Example from MSDN site:

```
class Program   
{   
   static void Main(string[] args)   
   {   
      ClientBase<ITest>.CacheSettings = CacheSettings.AlwaysOn;   
      foreach (string msg in messages)   
      {   
         using (TestClient proxy = new TestClient (new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(address)))   
         {   
            // ...  
            proxy.Test(msg);   
            // ...  
         }   
      }   
   }   
}  
// Generated by SvcUtil.exe     
public partial class TestClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase, ITest { }
```

As a result there is no need to custom implement that functionality as well mentioned in :

- [creating WCF ChannelFactory<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200197/creating-wcf-channelfactoryt/3201001#3201001)
- https://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/creating-a-wcf-service-proxy-with-channelfactory/

Also MSDN states that we should not use the C# "using" statement to automatically clean up resources when using a typed client and handle it with try/catch.

Example from MSDN site:

```
try  
{  
    ...  
    double result = client.Add(value1, value2);  
    ...  
    client.Close();  
}  
catch (TimeoutException exception)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());  
    client.Abort();  
}  
catch (CommunicationException exception)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());  
    client.Abort();  
}
```

1) Is the above way of calling a service safe to follow? Do I miss something? Or it's better to handle factory creation manually?

2) Am I going to have any problems with faulty states (both factory/channel)?

3) I need to create a new client for each service call right?